# How to shift a row by one Column?

Tags: r, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

A row shift a column to the right:

```
 col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1 A    A    A    A
2 B    B    B    B
3 NA   C    C    C    C
4 D    D    D    D
```

How can I move C back to its proper place?

I have tried the following but with no luck:

```
nc  <- ncol(df)
df[3, 1:nc] <- df[3, 2:(nc-1)]
```

Comment: `df[3, 1:(nc-1)] <- df[3, 2:nc]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do :

```
df[3, 1:(nc-1)] <- df[3, 2:nc]
```

then probably delete `col5` :

```
df$col5 <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use sed to preprocess the data, like:

```
sed -i 's/NA,//g' data.csv
```

Considering, data.csv being the original data file

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a `R` related answer, maybe I'm wrong on this. Please give some context to your answer. What is `sed`? In which package it is included?

Comment: sed is for 'stream editor', an UNIX utility.